# Calculate intersection point of two ellipses

Tags: geometry, intersection, ellipse

Given square outlines a circle with radius r. 
In the square, at it's left and upper sides, there are two identity ellipses with diameter d.
What is the distance between the intersection point of the ellipses (pointed by two arrows in the picture) and the left (or top) side of the square?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the circle is centered at `(0, 0)`.

Center of the horizontal ellipse = `(0, r - d/2)`

Horizontal radius = `r`

Vertical radius = `d/2`

Equation of the horizontal ellipse = `x^2/r^2 + (y -r + d/2)^2/(d/2)^2 = 1`.

Because of the symmetry, we also know that the two intersections satisfy `y = -x`. Then

```
x^2/r^2 + (x + r - d/2)^2/(d/2)^2 = 1
```

or

```
d^2/4 x^2 + r^2(x + (r - d/2))^2 = r^2d^2/4

(d^2/4 + r^2)x^2 + r^2(2r - d)x + r^2(r - d/2)^2 - r^2d^2/4 = 0

(d^2/4 + r^2)x^2 + r^2(2r - d)x + r^4 - r^3d = 0

(d^2/4 + r^2)x^2 + r^2(2r - d)x + r^3(r - d) = 0
```

and you can now complete the calculation solving this quadratic equation in `x`, etc.